# create a method to sort array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

unsorted array and integer k, create a method that rearrange the elements in array so that all elements less than or equal to k come before any elements larger than k.

here is my code and it doesnt work

```
public class SmallerFirst
{
    public int[] sort(int[] a, int k) 
    {

        if(a.length == 1)
        {
            return a;
        }

        if(a.length == 0)
        {
            return a;
        }

        else
        {
            int last = (a.length-1);
            for(int pos=0; pos<a.length; pos++)
            {
                for(int x=1;x>0;x++)
                {
                    if(last == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if(a[pos] > k)
                    {
                        swap(a,pos,last); last--; continue;
                    }           
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }       
            }
            return a;
        }
    }

    public void swap(int[] a,int p1,int p2)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        temp = a[p2];
        a[p2] = a [p1];
        a[p1]=temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: If its for class project, try solving yourself. otherwise use Arrays.sort(...) :)

Or else see the code of Arrays.sort

Comment: Do you need to save the order they appear in? Like `[1,3,5,2,10] k= 4` results in `[1,3,2,5,10]` ?

Comment: `for(int x=1;x>0;x++)` What is it?

Comment: I think he relies on the `break` statements. The `x` is unused anyway ... ugly, agree

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.sort(yourIntArray)` would be obvious choice.

Comment: not the most efficient way i guess ,this would sort the entire array but op i guess is ok with this 11,9,7,12,20,17,19 for element 12

Comment: I didn't claim providing the most efficient way, but probably the simplest :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want

```
public static void sort(int[] a, int k) {
    if(a.length > 1) {
        int last = (a.length-1),
            first = 0;
        while(last > first) {
            if(a[first] <= k) first++;
            else if(a[last] > k) last--;
            else swap(a, first, last);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> rearrange the elements in array so that all elements less than or
>   equal to k come before any elements larger than k.

- the problem **doesn't need the array to be sorted**.
- `Arrays.sort()` is handy, but it unnecessarily turns the `O(n)` problem into a `O(nlogn)` problem
- the straightforward solution is, time:`O(n)` and space `O(n)`, that is, you prepare an empty array, same size as input array, then loop through the input array, if the `element <= k`, put it into the empty array from left, otherwise put it from right side.
- it could be done by time `O(n)` and space `O(1)` though, (in place relocating), something like this may give you the result:

( the `a` would be the `int[]` array, and the `k` is the `k` in your problem)

```
    int p = -1; // flag pointer
    int w = 0; // working pointer

    for (; w <= a.length - 1; w++) {
        if (a[w] <= k) {
            p++;
            if (w != p) {
                swap(a, p, w);
            }
        }
    }
```